# How to check email sent or not in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a function to send a email for registered users. This is how i am checking if an email should be sent or not.

```
$email=$details->email;
$subject = 'Looking for blood donor';
$status=Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
                        use($subject,$email){
                        $message->from('no-reply@bloodlink.com', 'Blood Link');
                        $message->bcc('no-reply@bloodlink.com');
                        $message->to($email)->subject($subject);
                    });
```

I am using if for check email sent or not but it not work..

```
if($status)
{
    return Response::json(array('status'=>'success',
                                'data'=>("Your email has been sent successfully")
                         ), 200);
}else{
    return Response::json(array('status'=>'error',
                                'data'=>("something went wrong..!!")
                         ), 200);
}
```

Comment: first check dd($status) then what is your out put?

Comment: it give out put:2..what is the use of dd function..??

Comment: In Response, in else part, pass 500 status code  to return response.....

Comment: Did u configured the mail settings properly  in config/mail.php ?

Comment: yes i am properly confidured mail settings..email is send properly without error..what i am ask here how to cheack wheather mail is send or not to particular person

Answer (score 5):

The `Mail::send()` method doesn't return anything.

You can use the `Mail::failures()` (introduced in 4.1 I think) method to get an array of failed recipients, in your code it would look something like this.

```
Mail::send('emails.users.reset', compact('user', 'code'), function($m) use ($user)
{
    $m->to($user->email)->subject('Activate Your Account');
});

if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    $errors = 'Failed to send password reset email, please try again.';
}
```

Comment: i am tried your solution but it return empty result..      if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0){
    return Response::json(array(
                 'status'=>'error',
              'data'=>("something went wrong..!!"
               )
              ), 200);
}

Comment: empty result ?? what do you mean by that ?

Comment: it return emty result..without data..blank screen

Comment: what the above code does is , first it try to send email to the users, IF there occurs any failures, then it will show the errors . If you are getting blank page means, email is sent successfully .

Answer (score 2):

Have a look into failure method, [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.html#method_failures)

Comment: I never got an error thats why donot know exactly that how to use, I am just giving you example, you try it like this `$mail = Mail::send('emails .........` and `print_r($mail)` and 2nd method `Mail::send('emails ........., .... ,function($msg){ print_r($msg-> failures()); .... }` [check this](http://laravel.io/forum/08-08-2014-how-to-know-if-e-mail-was-sent)